# Is is possible - Refraction Shader without returning black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

So I`m trying to create fake refractive material without any reflections in Cycles, and I have already tried all tricks, is there really no way to get rid of these black zones?

I used Vray and Corona before and never had problem with that

For comparison - simple scene with a solid single color background, in Corona object is totally transparent so I had to add box behind to see it, while in Blender Cycles thosee black zones always appear
I`ve already tried increasing bounces, different mixing options but nothing gives the result at least same as corona or vray with 0 reflection/full refraction

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think there is a physical point of full refraction (or absorption) unless you turn the refractive index down to ```1.0```. If Corona already works like you need it to, I would stick to Corona.

Comment: Ray depth greater than desired number -> transparent bsdf, but in this environment it's going to be hard to see what refraction is doing